# convert string to date in sql where dates are incomplete

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date

I have an nvarchar(20) field which is being used to stored dates, which, due to the nature of the data, cannot be stored as an actual Date datatype, which I need to be able to do an ORDER BY on.

The problem is that some records have a full date, such as "01/01/2014" BUT other fields have only a year.

I need to be able to write the ORDER BY in such a way that regardless of if they have a complete date or not, that it will still order the records in the proper date order.

Comment: How would you propose to sort it in the proper order if the column contained 'BOB'?  If it's just a year, you could concatenate 01/01/ to the year, but there's no way to know if that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do

```
select *
from yourTable
order by cast(yourDate as date)
```

Which for any row that just has a year will default to 01/01 of that year. If there are other exceptions other than year you can do an `ISDATE()` check.

```
select *
from yourTable
where isdate(yourDate) = 1
order by cast(yourDate as date)
```

Comment: That is cool.  I didn't realize the MS SQL would convert years like that.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it would convert dates that way either, but that is perfect, and simple.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can do

```
select ifnull(
  str_to_date(datestring, '%m/%d/%Y'),
  str_to_date(concat(datestring, '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) as d
from t1 order by d
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d878/1